# How to make an background image seem like a single image

Tags: css, xhtml

How can I stop my background images to repeat? My question is more like how can to make my image set so that through out my whole web page it will seem like one image without seeing repetitions.

Comment: @raiyan106, were any of our responses helpful? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS3 snippet:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Vendor prefixes appear to be needed only to support Android 2.3; current version is 4.4. All other browsers appear to have supported `background-size` fully. http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size

Answer (score 0):

```
background-size: cover;                    
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "background-repeat: no-repeat;  " in your CSS.

```
#button {
    background: url('Images/image.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first read, it sounded like you were asking for:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

But if you want the image to stretch proportionally to fill the entire background, then you want:

```
background-size: cover;
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/viyay/1

```
#container {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/900/800);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">

    <!-- YOUR WEBSITE CONTENT HERE -->

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ALTERNATE DEMO (no stretch-to-fill): http://jsbin.com/dewucu/1

```
#container {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/300/300);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">

    <!-- YOUR WEBSITE CONTENT HERE -->

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```